# How to get raw pointer of box without consuming it?

Tags: pointers, rust

I need to pass a raw pointer to a struct to C++ and then still want to use that box afterwards.

I found the [into_raw](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) function but it eats the box and I can't use that box any more in Rust. Is there a way to get a `*const T`? I could get away with `const_cast` on C++ side.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```rust
let handle_ptr = Box::<Handle>::into_raw(handle);            
     
     
std::thread::spawn(move || {            
    let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread()            
        .build()            
        .unwrap();             
     
    rt.block_on( handle.run() );            
});            
     
return handle_ptr
```

I know that this is unsafe but I don't know any other way to allow C++ code running on other thread to call a thread-safe method of a Rust object.

Comment: Keeping the `Box` around after you've passed a pointer to another thread would allow you to drop it while the other thread is still running. How do you avoid that problem?

Comment: @trent I did not and It was bad idea. I'm regretting my choices now

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can dereference the box and cast the reference to its contents as a raw pointer:

```
let handle_ptr: *const Handle = &*handle;
```

Or:

```
let handle_ptr = &*handle as *const Handle;
```

Note that you haven't had to use `unsafe` yet. You'll need to use `unsafe` to dereference this pointer, including passing it to your C++ function. When you use `unsafe` the compiler can't help you, and it's up to you to ensure that Undefined Behaviour isn't triggered, which includes checking *safe* code that affects memory that's accessed in unsafe code.

In this case, your C++ function may use the pointer after the box is dropped (use after free). It's therefore up to you to make sure that this cannot happen.

---

See examples in the documentation for raw pointers:

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#common-ways-to-create-raw-pointers